# facebook ads not showing on android device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I use facebook ads in my android apps.I found that some test devices never show ads,no matter banner or interstitial.I wonder why and try to find the reason but it doesn't log any info and call the 'onError' method.Finally I found the common place between these devices is that these devices don't have facebook app installed on it.Then I try to install facebook app and then login.The ads really show up.I'm confused why this happen.

Is it necessary for facebook ads that facebook app must be installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary for facebook ads that facebook app must be installed and logined in with a Facebook account.

Comment: I just uninstalled Facebook on my device for testing, but Facebook ads still available for my device, how possible ?

Comment: @blackkara Maybe device and account infos have been uploaded to facebook server.

Comment: After a time, facebook ads became not visible for the apps having it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Audience Network ads require that Facebook are able to match the device id to a Facebook account. For testing you can instead use test ads, by specifying the device hashed id like so:

```
AdSettings.addTestDevice("HASHED ID");
```

This is easiest to find by checking console logs while ads are requested. You can also review the documentation here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing